# C++ Calling function inside another function

Tags: c++, function, coin-flipping

In my C++ class we've been given an assignment to make a coin toss program that has the random number generator in one function and it is called into another function that runs it twelve(12) times.

```
int cointToss()
{
return rand()%2;
}

int run12()
{
int face, heads=0;
for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    face=coinToss();

    if(face==1)
    {
        heads=heads+1;
    }
}
return heads;
}
```

Whenever I try to run it however I keep getting this error, "1>source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl coinToss(void)" (?coinToss@@YAHXZ)"

I can't seem to find a resource saying how to correctly call the first function inside of the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing.

You made a typo.  The function is called "cointToss", but you are calling "coinToss" (see the extra t?).

C implicitly added a function declaration for you.  Turn on warning, and you'll see.

Fix your typo, and the world will go round again.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is declared as `cointToss`, but you use `coinToss`.

Comment: I was thinking the spelling of the method looked weird, but I could not figure out why...